# Can't get prettier-plugin-tailwindcss to work on Nextjs App

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, prettier

So I had my nextjs app configured with tailwind normally then ran the command to `npm` install prettier and the prettier tailwind plugin and as I understand, it should work right away.

My default formatter in vscode is Prettier, I made sure of that and my files are formatted using Prettier when I save but the classes aren't sorted.

I didn't add any prettier config files or anything. Just my tailwind config file and that doesn't include anything related to the plugin either.

Something's wrong with the prettier plugin autoloading but idk how to fix it.

Answer (score 9):

I think this problem might be caused by changes in Prettier v3.0. You can try fixing it by going back to Prettier v2.8.8 with these steps:

```
npm uninstall prettier prettier-plugin-tailwindcss

npm install -D prettier@2.8.8 prettier-plugin-tailwindcss@0.4.1
```

[Plugin is incompatible with Prettier v3.0 - github issue](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/prettier-plugin-tailwindcss/issues/176)

**Edit:**

As of the prettier-plugin-tailwindcss version 0.5.4, this issue should now be resolved. You can update your dependencies with the following commands:

```
npm install -D prettier prettier-plugin-tailwindcss
```

Additionally, don't forget to include the following configuration in your prettier.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: ['prettier-plugin-tailwindcss'],
}
```

Lastly, make sure to reload Visual Studio Code for the changes to take effect. For more information, please refer to this [GitHub comment](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/prettier-plugin-tailwindcss/issues/207#issuecomment-1698071122).

Answer (score 1):

I am using Visual Studio Code Editor:

To begin, install `prettier-plugin-tailwindcss` as a dev dependency, which it seems you've already done:

`npm install -D prettier prettier-plugin-tailwindcss`

This command will install the latest versions of both Prettier and the Prettier Tailwind CSS plugin.

Next, you'll need to update your `package.json` file. Append the following configuration at the end:

```
"prettier": {
    "plugins": [
      "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"
    ]
  }
```

**Ensure your package.json mirrors this structure:**

[image]

This setup will integrate Tailwind CSS with Prettier in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Im my case next build had error in classes order and at the same time WebStorm IDE had no errors on those lines. I updated prettier-plugin-tailwindcss package and restarted IDE - works fine now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
cd ./node_modules/prettier-plugin-tailwindcss
npm i prettier
```

If u using prettier v3